# Spring Batch FornatterLineAggregator

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hi I am using Spring Batch **FlatFileItemWriter, FormatterLineAggregator and BeanWrapperFieldExtractor** to write more than 30,00,000 lines. During this process some how 2 or three lines are getting broken and not necesssarily the same lines are broken every time. Can some one please explain me about why is this happening?

**Here are the ColumnNames**

{"plantAbbrev", "deptCode","modelYearDate", "prodSchQty", "vehicleModelCode", "prodAsmLineNo","teamSeqNo", "teamNo", "bodyLocNo", "systemName", "processId", "asmProcNo", "unitId", "unitNo", "reportType", "cntrlMethod", "cntrlMethDesc", "unitOpDescText", "minTorqueValQty", "maxTorqueValQty"}

**Formatted Column Position**

"%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s%-6.6s%-10.10s%-1.1s%-4.4s%-4.4s%-4.4s%-50.50s%-9d%"
            + "-5.5s%-9d%-6.6s%-1.1s%-9.9s%-30.30s%-252.252s%-5.5s%-5.5s"

paticularly at the 18th position where I am writing 252 Characters are breaking every time.

Comment: what do you mean by "are getting broken"? Could you add an example of what is written and what should have been written? Are you sure, that there is no "linefeed" / "newline" character in your text?

Comment: Yes sorry, the line is braking because of the new line character